# Preventing the user from directly accessing mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Good Afternoon guys,

I'm currently trying to work out an authentication/login system for my python program using a MySQL database. I've noticed that using the MySQL connector I need to provide all the information required to access the database in order to read from it to verify usernames and passwords.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="Admin",
  password="******",
  database="authentication"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)
```

I was wondering if there was a way that I could allow the program to read from the mysql database without compromising any information that would allow a smart user direct access to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You gave the client access to your database and there are no methods to hide the password and prevent access.

Here are 3 ways to go to get what you might want:

1. Don't give root access to the client. Create another account with less privileges and store this data in your script.
2. Probably the better way: Use Tokens. The client receives a Token by a webserver after the verification and you check it every time the client accesses the database.
3. Use one of MYSQLs extern authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the credentials which ua passing to `connect()` .
Then you can search for cert based authentication (if that's available)

Then start to use secret management tools like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/use-cases/secrets-management) which provides many strategies to avoid risk of credentials/sensitive data leak.